# Dynamic allocation outside the scope of a function

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, malloc, storage-duration

If I want to create an array that works as global variable, in case I already know the size I can do it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int array[]={1,1,1,1};

int main()
{
    printf("%d", array[0]);
}
```

however, this will not work with `malloc`. Indeed, the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* array=malloc(4*sizeof(int));

int main()
{
    printf("%d", array[0]);
}
```

will return an error (`error: initializer element is not constant`). Yet there is no problem if I try to do the same inside the scope of the function.

I believe there must be something I am missing about how dynamic allocation works.

What is going on? How can define an array dynamically outside the scope of any function and the use them as a global variable?

Comment: Leave the definition of `array` outside the function, but assign it with `malloc` result in the function.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The  [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75138536/dynamic-allocation-outside-the-scope-of-a-function#comment132594780_75138536) to "assign it" makes sense if `Array` is not an _array_, but a pointer.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Sure. I addressed the second snippet, where `array` is a pointer.

Comment: Example 1 is "compile time allocation". Example 2 wants to be "run time allocation"... Executable code (ie: "run time") can only appear inside of functions, not outside.

Answer (score 4):

In C language the code can be executed only in the function bodies.

The second code is invalid as you try to call `malloc` outside the function.

Using global variables in C is considered as a bad practice, so try to avoid it if not 100% necessary.

If you want to have a global pointer:

```
int *array;

int main(void)
{
     array = malloc(100);
     /* .... */
}
```

Some compilers support non-standard extensions. For example, in GCC you can use the attribute to execute the code before the function `main` is called

```
int* array;

void __attribute__((constructor)) aray_const(void)
{
    array = malloc(4 *sizeof(*array));
    if(array) memcpy(array, (int[]){1,2,3,4}, 4 * sizeof(*array));
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]);
     /* .... */
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bz4YjzfK5

Answer (score 3):

In C objects with static storage duration may be initialized by a constant expression. And the pointer `array` declared in your second program in the file scope has static storage duration as any object declared in file scope.

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> **4 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
> or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
> literals.**

Also the function `malloc` allocates non-initialized memory. So this call of printf

```
printf("%d", array[0]);
```

in any case can invoke undefined behavior.

You can rewrite your program for example the following way using the assignment operator in main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *array;

int main( void )
{
    size_t n = 4;
    array = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( array != NULL )
    {
        int value = 1;
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            array[i] = value++;
        }

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {   
            printf( "%d ", array[i] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    free( array );
}
```

Or you could use function `calloc` instead of `malloc`. In this case the allocated memory will be zero-initialized.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *array;

int main( void )
{
    size_t n = 4;
    array = calloc( n, sizeof( int ) );

    if ( array != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {   
            printf( "%d ", array[i] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    free( array );
}
```

Pay attention to that you should always free allocated memory when it is not required any more.

Comment: The reason it's like this, is that the compiler works out all the bytes in your global variables and stores them directly in the program file. If you call something like malloc, the compiler doesn't know what bytes go in the variable. It can't call malloc when it's still compiling.

Comment: Re “Also the function malloc allocates non-initialized memory. So this call of printf `printf("%d", array[0]);` in any case will invoke undefined behavior.”: In C implementations without trap representations in the `int` type, the behavior of the code is not undefined; it must print an `int` value. If the implementation does have a trap representation in the `int` type, the code may generate a trap but otherwise must print an `int` value.